# Cannot resolve method 'setContentUrl'

Tags: android, image, methods

I want to share an image in my application.

This is my layout file

activity_xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.dc.google.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/share_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Share on Google+"
        />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

This is my java class file

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.dc.google;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Button shareButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.share_button);
        shareButton.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Launch the Google+ share dialog with attribution to your app.
                Intent shareIntent = shareButton.setText("Welcome to Google+")
                    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.google.com/+/"))
                    .getIntent();

                startActivityForResult(shareIntent,0);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here the `.setContentUrl` shows an error saying `the method can not be resolved.`
I can't find the solution.
How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Well, what are you trying to call that method on? `setText` is a void method...

Comment: And when you say you can't find something. 1) Read the error message. There's lot's of things wrong with those three lines of code there. 2) Read the API documentation. 3) What makes you think `setContentUrl` is a valid method at all?

Answer (score 0):

Need to [read the documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share/) again...

You shouldn't `setText` on your button... You `setText` on a `new PlusShare.Builder`

Worry about sharing an image once you get code that will compile. (Hint: that documentation also shows [sharing images](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share/media)).

```
Button shareButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.share_button);
shareButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      // Launch the Google+ share dialog with attribution to your app.
      Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(MainActivity.this)
          .setType("text/plain")
          .setText("Welcome to the Google+ platform.")
          .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.google.com/+/"))
          .getIntent();

      startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);
    }
});
```